# Errors after Theano upgrade from 0.7 to bleeding edge

Tags: theano

I installed and used Theano 0.7 and everything was working perfectly. But now for the purpose of my future works, I need the bleeding edge version, and the installation went fine.

But when I run this [little test](http://www.thibault.biz/StackOverflow/Theano/tests.py) (found into the Theano documentation), it generates many errors ([see here for the full list](http://www.thibault.biz/StackOverflow/Theano/errors.txt)).

- We can observe that the GPU is detected and used, but cuDNN is not found anymore:

`Using gpu device 0: GeForce GT 650M (CNMeM is enabled with initial size: 65.0% of memory, CuDNN not available)`

- And then I have an import error, I think it is also about cuDNN:

`ImportError: ('The following error happened while compiling the node', <theano.sandbox.cuda.DnnVersion object at 0x114d32710>(), '\n', 'dlopen(/Users/FiReTiTi/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-13.4.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-2.7.11-64/tmpwmA_hw/265abc51f7c376c224983485238ff1a5.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcudnn.4.dylib\n  Referenced from: /Users/FiReTiTi/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-13.4.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-2.7.11-64/tmpwmA_hw/265abc51f7c376c224983485238ff1a5.so\n  Reason: image not found', '[<theano.sandbox.cuda.DnnVersion object at 0x114d32710>()]')`

I've checked and cudnn.h is still in `/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/include/`, in `/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/lib/` we still find libcudnn.dylib which is a symbolic link to libcudnn.4.dylib, and everything in `/usr/local/cuda` points to `/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/`

Any idea?

[EDIT] In my .profile we find:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

In `/usr/local/cuda/lib` there is a symbolic link to the cudnn library that is actually in `/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/lib`.

Here is the result from the command `tool -L libcudnn.4.dylib`:

```
libcudnn.4.dylib:
@rpath/libcudnn.4.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 4.0.7)
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 855.14.0)
/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
```

And here is the link between: `/usr/local/cuda/lib/libcudnn.dylib -> /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/lib/libcudnn.dylib`, and in `/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/lib` I have `libcudnn.dylib -> libcudnn.4.dylib`

[EDIT 2]

```
$ echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/xuggler/lib:/usr/local/cuda/lib:/Applications/IMOD/lib:

$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/cuda/lib:
```

[EDIT 3]  [Here is the last error](http://www.thibault.biz/StackOverflow/Error.txt) displayed. At least one part, because this error appears at each epoch.

With `ls -la /usr/local/cuda/lib`:

```
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    45B 22 fév 11:42 libcudnn.dylib -> /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/lib/libcudnn.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    48B 26 fév 01:01 libcudnn_static.a -> /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/lib/libcudnn_static.a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in Theano. It probably would work if they added `["-Wl,-rpath,%s" % l for l in c_lib_dirs()]` to the compile args. You should report that upstream [here](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues).

It might work as a workaround if you add the path of `libcudnn.4.dylib` to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (or maybe `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`) environment variable, because that is where `@rpath` will also look at, so that the path `@rpath/libcudnn.4.dylib` can be resolved.

Comment: I checked and all the paths are good. The Theano guys also think that's a bug on the Mac OS X version.

Comment: @FiReTiTi: Where is libcudnn.4.dylib? Can you show your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`? Can you show the output of `otool -L libcudnn.4.dylib`?

Comment: I've edited my question in order to answer to yours.

Comment: That doesn't fully answer my question. To get the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (and other vars), type `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. It could have been modified after your `.profile` was loaded. Also, I don't exactly know what you mean with "there is a symbolic link". How is the symlink called? Can you show it? It's very unclear. Type `ls -la <whatever-file-you-mean>` and post that output (with full path so that it's clear). `otool -L libcudnn.4.dylib` only works if you go into the directory where you find the file `libcudnn.4.dylib`. What directory is that?

Comment: Done. But ouch, the echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH is empty. Does it mean that somewhere a script/soft erases whatever I put in my .profile?

Comment: Ok, it seems that the .profile file is never read, only the .bash_profile. how can I say to the .bash_profile to call the .profile?

Comment: I've fixed the .profile loading issue, but cudnn is still not available.

Comment: @FiReTiTi: So what is the content of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`? You still did not explicitly say that. Just post the output of what I wrote (`echo ...`). (Also, in your `.profile`, you only specify `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, not `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.)

Comment: @FiReTiTi: That last ":" in the env vars might be problematic. Better remove it. Also, has your Theano output changed somehow? Do you still get the same ImportError? Can you post the full output?

Comment: @FiReTiTi: Btw, `/usr/local/cuda/lib` is not the directory with `libcudnn.4.dylib`. That file is only in `/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/lib`. So you need to add that directory to both env vars.

Comment: I am gonna check for the ':' issue and I will share the full error. In /usr/local/cuda/lib there is a link to /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/lib/libcudnn.4.dylib

Comment: The last ':' does not change anything.

Comment: @FiReTiTi: That is not what you wrote before. You wrote that there is only `libcudnn.dylib`, not `libcudnn.4.dylib`. Are you sure? Can you post the output of `ls -la /usr/local/cuda/lib`?

Comment: libcudnn.dylib is a link to libcudnn.4.dylib. It is provided like that on NVIDIA website.

Comment: @FiReTiTi: Yes, so there is no `/usr/local/cuda/lib/libcudnn.4.dylib`. So, as I wrote, you can fix your problem by adding `/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/lib` to your env vars.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Final question: why the symbolic link is not followed and then the libcudnn.4.dylib not added?

Comment: It just tries to resolve `@rpath/libcudnn.4.dylib`. `@rpath` is whatever your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (or maybe the DYLD... version) contains. So, that file is simply not there. There is no clever logic that it automatically checks for `@rpath/libcudnn.dylib` or so in that case. And how else would it find `/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/lib`?

Comment: When Cuda is install, it creates a link between /usr/local/cuda/ and all the libraries in /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/lib. So I just did the same with cudnn, thinking that it would also work.

Comment: @FiReTiTi: No, it does not. You posted the directory content of `/usr/local/cuda/`. There is only `libcudnn.dylib`, not `libcudnn.4.dylib`. `/usr/local/cuda/libcudnn.4.dylib` does not exist. Check yourself: `ls -la /usr/local/cuda/libcudnn.4.dylib`.